# Kinect v2 obtain x,y,z from mouse click using Color image and Depth Image c#

Tags: c#, kinect

I am new in kinect and I am trying to develop an app where the user can click on a specific location on the Color Image and obtain the x,y,z coordinates.

I am first trying to display the Color Stream Image and the depth stream image where the user should be able to select a point.

I would like to show the point that the user is selecting on the color image and the depth image.

Answer (score 1):

The (x,y,z) coordinate point is known as [`CameraSpacePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx).

Using [`CoordinateMapper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.aspx) Class You can Map [`ColorFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.aspx)  to `CameraSpace` using [`MapColorFrameToCameraSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.mapcolorframetocameraspace.aspx) Method.

To Map [`DepthFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.depthframe.aspx) to `CameraSpace` use [`MapDepthFrameToCameraSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.mapdepthframetocameraspace.aspx) Method.

To understand How to use `Coordinate Mapper` Class, click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785530.aspx).

Also you can see the Coordinate Mapping Basics-WPF sample in SDK Browser (Kinect for windows) v2.

Comment: But since he only wants to find the (x,y,z) coordinates of a single point, for the `DepthFrame` he should probably use [`MapDepthPointToCameraSpace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.mapdepthpointtocameraspace.aspx).

Comment: Thank you both for you answers :-D That's what I tried but it's always telling me that my CameraSpacePoint is never assigned and will always have its default value

Comment: @Lou-AnnRaymond Have you initialized `CameraSpacePoint` array?

Comment: Yes I initialize it but I found another way to define the x,y,z using IR x,y and then using z from depth frame data knowing that it's coming from the same camera. Thank you very much :-)